# Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: no declaration can be found for element 'jpa:repositories'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I saw this same query and multiple answers in Stack Overflow, but nothing worked for me. As none of the solutions worked in my case, wondering if there is something else left to try!

Exception :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 49 in XML document from URL [file:/C:/xxx/xxx-data/target/classes/xxx-data-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 49; columnNumber: 172; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jpa:repositories'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
```

This is how my XML starts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
```

This is the line where the exception points to :

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="au.com.xxxxxxx.xxx.data.dao.bth" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory-slg" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager-slg"/>
```

I tried with and without version for JPA, with and without HTTPS, validated the XML and what not, but nothing worked.

Note: I tried commenting the jpa:repositories tag and then got into the next issue:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'beans' 

    cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the issue while running a test. How I fixed this issue was by commenting `<jpa:repositories>` and adding this annotation to the test class :

`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.abc.xxx.data.*"}, entityManagerFactoryRef="entityManagerFactory-xyz")`

This error seems to be very misleading. This is the best possible solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59487936/3480525

But since that didn't work for me, I had to comment it out and add annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on search I found 2 pattern worth trying, may or may not work.

1 `xmlns:tx` declaration is missing

2 order of schema should be `context, tx, jpa`

refering to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542616/no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-jparepositories) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884328/spring-config-xml-isnt-valid-after-adding-spring-data-jpa-schema-references)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. I tried copy pasting this, didn't work! What else can be the issue!